# PHP ODBC and MSSQL encoding

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, character-encoding

i have a mssql database and php connection via ODBC driver and system DSN

my database encoding is :

```
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

my db contain some arabic fields which appear fine at database but when i got them to my php page they appear like this :

```
??? ??????? ? ?????? ???????? ???????? ????? ??????? ???????? � ???? ?????? ???
```

i have tried a lot of options but i didn't succeed to convert them to be readable !

does i miss any thing here !

Comment: Maybe you can sitch to "SQL Server Driver for PHP", which allows to pass CharacterSet = "UTF-8" as driver_options. Anyway, this is most likely caused by messed up encodings you should take a look at php.ini's default_charset, your file encoding and in which encoding your responses are returned to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change how windows treat non English applications from 
control panel->regional and settings